# XGBRegressor.fit() fails with 'no kernel image is available for execution'

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost

I have the following code using xgboost's `XGBRegressor`:

```
X_train, Y_train = load_train()

from xgboost import XGBRegressor
regressor = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1, verbose=3, n_jobs=1, objective='reg:squarederror')
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

When I run it in python3, it crashes the interpreter with the following output:

```
[23:02:57] WARNING: /workspace/src/learner.cc:686: Tree method is automatically selected to be 'approx' for faster speed. To use old behavior (exact greedy algorithm on single machine), set tree_method to 'exact'.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  parallel_for failed: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

It seems that the source of the error message is CUDA which probably means that xgboost tries to use GPU for training. Here https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/index.html they say that

> CUDA 9.0, Compute Capability 3.5 required

My GPU (GTX 760) only supports Compute Capability 3.0, so this probably could be the problem.

So I am trying to tell xgboost to only use CPU. Here https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.rst we can find `predictor` parameter that should be passed via `kwargs` parameter of the `XGBRegressor` constructor.

But the following does not help:

```
regressor = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1, verbose=3, n_jobs=1, objective='reg:squarederror', predictor='cpu_predictor')
```

Is it possible to avoid using a GPU altogether? How do I solve the problem?

xgboost version is 0.90.

Answer (score 1):

XGBoost doesn't make best use of your CPU power. If you want to squeeze all the juice out of your CPU, go with LightGBM.